# Python custom decorator class exhibiting strange behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, higher-order-functions, magic-methods

I was trying to develop a python library for using monads (a toy project to understand both monads and how python can act as a "purely functional" language), but this question has nothing to do with monads or functional programming.

In the need of an operator to compose functions, I tried the following "decorator class":

```
class Composable(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self._func(*args)

    def _compose(self, func):
        @Composable
        def _func(*args):
            return func(self._func(*args))
        return _func

    def __mul__(self, func):
        return self._compose(other)
```

It should be used as inside the "_compose" method, and it works flawlessly if i use it for "plain function decoration". That is, the following code works fine:

```
@Composable
def function1(n):
    return n + 1

@Composable
def function2(n):
    return n * 2

print((function1 * function2)(5)) #outputs (5 * 2) + 1 = 11
```

The thing that i don't understand is that, if i decorate two function decorators with "Composable", i won't be able to directly compose them as decorators, using the "multiplication" operator as i did before:

```
@Composable
def decorator1(func):
    def decorated(n):
        return func(n) + 1
    return decorated

@Composable
def decorator2(func):
    def decorated(n):
        return func(n) * 2
    return decorated

#This triggers a "SyntaxError" (with or without enclosing parentheses)
@decorator1 * decorator2
def function(n):
    return n

#While this works fine
@decorator1._compose(decorator2)
def function(n):
    return n

#Not quite surprisingly, this works fine too
@decorator1.__mul__(decorator2)

#(as always, this outputs (5 * 2) + 1 = 11)
function(5)
```

My point is: i "was told" (see [the mul magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#object.__mul__) and [python decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.4.html?highlight=decorator#pep-318-decorators-for-functions-and-methods)) that

```
a * b
```

is not much more than syntactic sugar for

```
a.__mul__(b)
```

and that

```
@decorator
def f(n):
    pass
```

is nothing more than

```
def f(n):
    pass
f = decorator(f)
```

So here is my question: what is going on here? Aren't decorators the result of the evaluation of any expression that returns a callable?

Oh, and if anyone was wondering: i'm using python3.5

Comment: I don't think that `@decorator1` in `@decorator1 * decorator2` is an object.

Comment: You're mixing salt into the syntactic sugar! No, you cannot multiply decorators when using the `@` syntax; you can see [in the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) that it's not legal grammar.

Comment: See also [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#id30): "The decorator statement is limited in what it can accept -- arbitrary expressions will not work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) provides the grammar for a decorator:

```
decorator ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
```

Both `decorator1._compose` and `decorator1.__mul__` are grammatically `dotted_name`s, hence that is valid syntax. `@decorator1 * decorator2`, however, clearly doesn't match.

"Syntactic sugar" does not mean being able to directly replace parts of one form with parts of another. The form:

```
@decorator
def f(n):
    pass
```

is certainly *equivalent to*:

```
def f(n):
    pass
f = decorator(f)
```

but they aren't the same and aren't entirely interchangeable.

Comment: I see. Is that why 

    @(decorator1 * decorator2)
    def function(n):
        pass
gives an error too?

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone yes; you cannot have arbitrary expressions, only a dotted name followed optionally by parentheses, which themselves optionally contain arguments.